# Replacing Text Online with Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

A newbie at Applescript here. I'm trying to make a script that scans text in a text editor online and replaces words with other words.

In my specific case, it's replacing a few html snippets with nothing "" — i.e. deleting them.

My current script gets the following error message… *"Brave Browser got an error: window 1 doesn’t understand the “execute” message." number -1708 from window 1*

Here's the script below. The line that is problematic seems to be where the **EditorField** variable comes in.

Any pointers or ideas out there to get this working? Thanks.

```
    tell application "Brave Browser"
        activate
        my replaceWordWithStringInBodyText("&nbsp;", "")
        my replaceWordWithStringInBodyText("<span class=\"Apple-converted-space\">", "")
        my replaceWordWithStringInBodyText("<b>", "<strong>")
    end tell

    on replaceWordWithStringInBodyText(searchWord, replacementString)
        tell application "Brave Browser"
            activate
            tell window 1
                set EditorField to (execute javascript "document.getElementById('\"wp-content-editor-container\"')")
                tell EditorField
                    -- start at the end and go to the beginning
                    repeat with i from the (count of paragraphs) to 1 by -1
                        tell paragraph i
                            repeat
                                try
                                    if exists searchWord then
                                        set (last word where it is searchWord) to replacementString
                                    else
                                        exit repeat
                                    end if
                                on error errorMessage
                                    exit repeat
                                end try
                            end repeat
                        end tell
                    end repeat
                end tell
            end tell
            return true
        end tell
    end replaceWordWithStringInBodyText
```

Comment: BTW, and this is not the cause of the error you're getting, however change `('\"wp-content-editor-container\"')` to `('wp-content-editor-container')` as there is no need to use escaped double-quotes inside of the single-quotes. Additionally, it's always a good idea to include the **URL** of the target page, assuming it's accessible to everyone, so we can test the _code_ against the same as you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming in the **Brave** browser you've clicked **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events**, to have it checked, on the **View** > **Developer** menu.

With that said and since you have not included a **URL** to test your *code* with, let me put forth an example of how I'd click the **Ask Question** button, in the upper right-hand corner, if I was at this question in the **Brave** browser:

```
tell application "Brave Browser" to tell active tab of front window to execute javascript ¬
    "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
```

As you can see, one must also communicate with the *target tab* as well as the *target window*. So you'll need to adjust your *code* accordingly.

Comment: Great help, thank you! The script now runs without throwing up an error message, only problem is that the script doesn't actually replace anything in the text still.

I can't share a direct link since it's private but it's a WordPress draft post using the built-in HTML editor in the WordPress post editor - don't know if anyone is familiar with using this and might have any ideas?